# How to create the table of frequency for a list that contains arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list that has a few hundred thousand arrays of the same size. I need to remove the first element in each array and then create a table of frequency using `np.unique(my_array,return_counts=True)`.

For instance, consider

```
data = [[0,1,5,6,3,4,5],[2,3,1,2,4,0,5],[9,7,0,2,4,0,3],[8,7,1,7,4,0,2]]
```

How do I find the number of times each of the unique values comes up in the above list data. Since my data is big, I need a fast method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn `data` into numpy array for advanced slicing:

```
np.unique(np.array(data)[:,1:], return_counts=True)
```

Output:

```
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]), array([4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! Do we remove the first element in each array with your method here? I first need to remove the first item in each array and then create the table of frequency of the remaining list.

Comment: @lynx Yes, he does.  Not 0 has a count of 4, ignoring the zero in the first position of the first list.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you very much for explaining! 
The answer is an awesome life-saving touch.